# Como ligar o flash da câmera?

Tags: java, android, android-camera

Não estou conseguindo ativar o flash da câmera para utilizar como lanterna. O código que estou executando peguei de tutoriais na internet.

```
package com.getten.home;

import android.hardware.Camera;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;

public class Login extends ActionBarActivity {

    private Toolbar pToolbar;

    private Camera mCamera;
    private boolean lFlashLigado = false;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.login);

        pToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        pToolbar.setLogo(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
        setSupportActionBar(pToolbar);

        try {
            mCamera = Camera.open();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            Log.e("Camera", "Impossível ouvir a câmera!");
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        if (mCamera != null) {
            mCamera.release();
            mCamera = null;
        }
        super.onPause();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        if (item.getItemId() == R.id.lanterna) {
            ligaDesligaFlash(lFlashLigado);
        }

        return true;
    }

    private void ligaDesligaFlash(boolean lDesliga) {
        if (lDesliga) {
            if (mCamera != null) {
                Camera.Parameters params = mCamera.getParameters();
                params.setFlashMode(Camera.Parameters.FLASH_MODE_OFF);
                mCamera.setParameters(params);
                mCamera.startPreview();

                lFlashLigado = false;
            }
        } else {
            if (mCamera != null) {
                Camera.Parameters params = mCamera.getParameters();
                params.setFlashMode(Camera.Parameters.FLASH_MODE_TORCH);
                mCamera.setParameters(params);
                mCamera.startPreview();

                lFlashLigado = true;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Estou compilando o aplicativo na versão "22". Já adicionei tudo que é permissão, mas também não tive sucesso:

```xml
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FLASHLIGHT"/>
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" />
```

Alguém saberia como solucionar, ou alguma outra forma de fazer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Primeiro você deve alterar seu `AndroidManifest.xml` e adicionar as permissões:

```
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
  <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
  <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" />
```

Após isso no evento onClick de um botão faça o seguinte código:

```
private Camera mCamera;

public void ligarLed(View v) {
    mCamera = Camera.open();
    if( mCamera != null ){
            Parameters params = mCamera.getParameters();
            params.setFlashMode( Parameters.FLASH_MODE_TORCH );
            mCamera.setParameters( params );
     }
}
```

O que muda para Ligar ou Desligar o Flash é o enumerador

```
Parameters.FLASH_MODE_TORCH
Parameters.FLASH_MODE_OFF
```

Não se esqueça que após usar o Flash deve liberar a câmera com o seguinte código:

```
mCamera.release();
mCamera = null;
```

Comment: O erro citado anteriormente ocorre no momento em que executo o `camera = Camera.open();` 

@Eduardo binotto, desenvolvi exatamente como me orientou, e o mesmo erro persiste. Será que pode ser alguma configuração do celular, é um Xperia (Android 5.0.2)?

Comment: Boa Noite @Maicon, você pode colocar um `try catch` e enviar o erro que está acontecendo para que possamos analisar e encontrar uma solução para este problema.

Comment: Primeira obrigado pela ajuda pessoal...
A mensagem de erro que exibe é: 'Fail to connect to camera service'.
Código utilizado: 
` try{
            camera = Camera.open();
        }catch(Exception ex){
            Log.e("err", ex.getMessage());
        } `

Comment: Estive analisando melhor seu código, e você só esta liberando sua câmera no onPause.

Altere o código do onPause e coloque em seu método ligaDesligaFlash.
O erro é porque a câmera não esta disponível.

Comment: Eduardo, achei o problema: 
Eu estava inserindo as permissões dentro da tag `application` .... Depois que joguei os `uses-permission` fora ele funcionou. 
No console do Android Studio ainda aparece algumas mensagens de falha de conexão, no entanto, o flash está funcionando. 

Valeu pela ajuda! 
Obrigado.

Comment: Que bom que conseguiu, fico muito feliz em conseguir te ajudar. Se puder colocar minha respostas como a melhor para a perguta fico muito agradecido. Obrigado.

Answer (score 1):

Primeiro de tudo:

```
<uses-sdk android:minsdkversion="11" android:targetsdkversion="17">
```

Basicamente você precisa de:

```
//Ligar camera
camera = Camera.open();
Parameters p = camera.getParameters();
p.setFlashMode(Parameters.FLASH_MODE_TORCH);
camera.setParameters(p);
camera.startPreview();  

//DesLigar camera
camera = Camera.open();
Parameters p = camera.getParameters();
p.setFlashMode(Parameters.FLASH_MODE_OFF);
camera.setParameters(p);
camera.stopPreview();
```

O problema pode está na sua condicional. Tente utilizar o evento `OnClickListener`:

```
    ....
    //Detectando se o flash está ligado, inicialmente sim
    private boolean isLighOn = false;

    private Camera camera;

    private Button button;

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();

        if (camera != null) {
            camera.release();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.botaoFlash);

        Context context = this;
        PackageManager pm = context.getPackageManager();

        // O mais importante: O aparelho possui configuração para câmera?
        if (!pm.hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_CAMERA)) {
            Log.e("err", "Aparelho não suporta camera!");
            return;
        }

        camera = Camera.open();
        final Parameters p = camera.getParameters();

        button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {

                if (isLighOn) {

                    Log.i("informação", "Desligado!");

                    p.setFlashMode(Parameters.FLASH_MODE_OFF);
                    camera.setParameters(p);
                    camera.stopPreview();
                    isLighOn = false;

                } else {

                    Log.i("informação", "ligado!");

                    p.setFlashMode(Parameters.FLASH_MODE_TORCH);

                    camera.setParameters(p);
                    camera.startPreview();
                    isLighOn = true;

                }

            }
        });

    }
}
```

Comment: Valeu... Acredito ser um problema com o 
<uses-sdk android:minsdkversion="11" android:targetsdkversion="17">

Vou fazer o teste criando o app nestas versões.

Comment: Confirma aqui se der certo.

Comment: Não consegui fazer funcionar. A mensagem de erro apresentada é: 

java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.teste.flash/com.teste.flash.flash}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Fail to connect to camera service